# setting nil background for UILabel for iphone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, uibackgroundcolor

I have a UILabel , here is the code i have written:

```
UILabel *tl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 50, 30)];
tl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
tl.backgroundColor = nil;
// tl.text = @"123"; // 1
tl.text = @"你好"; // 2
tl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:tl];
```

like annotation 1, if you set it in [English or number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOoJp.jpg), the whole UILabel becomes balck, 
but if it is set in [Chinese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlY2v.jpg), it is normal color.

Comment: what is your expected behavior?

Comment: set `tl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: i want to keep his background color consistent with his superview,but the superview sometimes appears the backgroud color of the nil,     eg: tl.backgroundColor = [[tl superview] backgroundColor];

Comment: give superview background color white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fengshaobo use `[UIColor clearColor];` in background color

Comment: not possible. i have copy your code and run in my mac and told you solution.. replace this code with your nil code.. `tl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Comment: what is your view's background color ?

Comment: give white color to your superview background color.

Comment: sorry,there is some errors in the code ,it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is `[UIColor clearColor]`. Don't use `nil`

```
tl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```